# How To Filter And Limit Attributes Of A Group Object In An LDAP

Tags: java, search, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I want to get users of a group in an LDAP, with a given filter(Ex: uid="test*") and a limit(only 10 users in the results).

The group object looks like below.

```
cn=testRole,ou=Groups,dc=WSO2,dc=ORG
```

This object has multiple member attributes representing users of the role "testRole".

Now I'm using the following query to retrieve all the users in the group.

```
(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=testRole))
```

And `member` is set as the returned attribute.

When I run the query, all the 10000 users in the *testRole* are retrieved(as 10000 member attribute values).

Now,

1. How do I limit the number of member attribute values?
2. How do I filter member attribute values by applying a filter to the value of it's `uid`?

Thanks in advance!

I tried setting the returned attribute as `member;range=0-99` but seems like it only works with AD, not with LDAP. I need a solution that would work with LDAP regardlessly it is an AD or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it's not possible as is with openLDAP. An idea would be to setup the `memberof` overlay in the first place so you can grab user entries - not by querying the group and fetching all `member` attributes - but by directly querying users that are `memberOf` this group. In this situation, you would be able to paginate the results with the desired range. Not to mention that you will also be able to filter by a specific member eg. `(&(memberOf=<groupDN>)(uid=<uid>))` (which I think is what you ask in 2-). See these links :

   - [How to enable memberOf](https://www.adimian.com/blog/2014/10/how-to-enable-memberof-using-openldap/)
   - [Simple Paged Results Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/paged-results.html).
2. You can use the following filter :

   ```
   (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=testRole)(member=uid=<uid>,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com))
   ```

   But remember this query just grabs a groupOfNames entry with cn=testRole and containing a member with dn=..., adding the `member` filter here would just prevent the entry to match in case the member's `<uid>` does not exist, any matching uid would not change anything.

I think you can also keep the query as it is, iterating member attributes by range of x to y using java shouldn't be too hard, it all depends on what you need to do with it.